# could not fetching rows content for more then 1000 rows on Azure Table

Tags: python-3.x, azure

i'm trying to catch content on rows more than 1000.

So i have tried to append each content on list to be able to use it then.

## coding:utf-8

```
import os
import json
from azure import *
from azure.storage import *
from azure.storage.table import TableService, Entity
import datetime


def Retrives_datas():

    twenty_hours_before_now = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    now = twenty_hours_before_now.isoformat()
    filter = "Timestamp gt datetime'" + now + "'"
    maker = None
    i=0
    table_service = TableService(account_name='MyAccount', sas_token='MySAS')
    while True:
        tasks  = table_service.query_entities('MyTable', filter = filter, timeout=None, num_results=1000, marker=maker)
        for task in tasks:
            i += 1
            print(i,tasks.items[i]['Status'])
        if tasks.next_marker != {}:
            maker = tasks.next_marker
        else:
            break
```

i get the below error :

999 Success

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       print(i,tasks.items[i]['Status']) IndexError: list index out of range

knowing that i when i replace

```
print(i,tasks.items[i]['Status'])
```

by

```
print(i)
```

I get more than 2770 rows.

Comment: Hi,would you please mark the answer for others' reference,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common error `list index out of range` because that you want to access the list[1000] even though it only has 1000 items(you set `num_results=1000` ). You could only access list[999] because the index starts with 0.

Just move down `i += 1` line.

```
for task in tasks:

    print(i,tasks.items[i]['Status'])
    i += 1
```

My sample data:

[image]

Output:

[image]

---

For summary, the length of the `tasks.item` takes the size of the next list that will be returned instead incrementation.

Solution: Added if  `i == <num_results>: i = 0`

Comment: I have tried your solution but I'm facing the same issue. IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: have you logged the last value of `i`,it is 999 or 1000? Or you could try to access the value of tasks.items[999]['Status'],it still occurs the same error?

Comment: Yes i get the same issue :

    print(tasks.items[999]['Status'])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @MEZIANEYacine Please jump into this chat room please :https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193816/blob-item

Comment: @MEZIANEYacine Please show the length of the items array:  `print(len(tasks.items))`

Comment: Sorry, i don't have enough reputation to talk on the chat.
I've added the line print(len(tasks.items)) like below : 

for task in tasks:
            print("i=",i)
            i += 1
        if tasks.next_marker != {}:
            maker = tasks.next_marker
        else:
            break
print("len=",len(tasks.items))

And the result is : 
i = 1522
len = 0

Comment: Not yet i've only 14. 
I've tried and len = 0 

for task in tasks: 
    print("i=",i) 
    i += 1 
    if tasks.next_marker != {}: 
        maker = tasks.next_marker 
    else: 
        break 
    print("len=",len(tasks.items)) 

And the result is : 
i = 1522 
len = 0

Comment: Now i've 19 may be if i post this comment i will be able to connect to chat.

Comment: @MEZIANEYacine Just remove any other loop code,only leave the `print("len=", len(tasks.items))`, it still shows zero?

Comment: @MEZIANEYacine So,here is to locate the reason why the length of `tasks.items` is `zero`,regardless of other code. It's zero, of course, `list index out of range` will be posted out if you access  the list.

Comment: I've retry with the last code and i = 1522 and len = 523.

After, i'v tried with your second suggestion and len=1000.

Comment: I think that is my bad connexion that not allow me to retrives all rows for each time. It's what i get somtimes len = 0. But i've retried and i = 1522 and len = 523.

Comment: i dont know why but as soon as we reach the 1000 th row, lenght takes the size of the next list that will be returned instead incrementation. 
For exemple if we have 1200 rows. first, len(tasks.items) = 1000  as soon we get the 1000 first rows, len(tasks.items) = 200 instead 1200.

Comment: I've resolved the issue. I have added if i == 1000: i = 0. and it's work fine :)

Comment: @MEZIANEYacine Great! I summarized it in my answer, you could mark my answer for others' reference,thank you!